# How to get user roles

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a ticket system for my bot.  It used to work, but now no longer does and I'm not sure why.

In the past I've tried to use discord.Role(role_id) but got the following error.

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here is my current code.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def maketicket(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    author = ctx.message.author
    reason = ctx.message.content[12:] #subject of ticket


    everyone = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)
    staff = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)


    eyedee = random.randrange(1,99999) #assigns id number
    name = "ticket-" + str(eyedee)

    await client.create_channel(server, name, (server.default_role, everyone), (ctx.message.author, staff))
    ticket = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name = "ticket-" + str(eyedee)) #makes variable to easily call on the channel

    admin = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Administrator")
    await client.edit_channel_permissions(ticket, admin, staff)
```

When I run the code as shown above, I get this error.

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: target parameter must be either Member or Role
```

Comment: How are you invoking this command?

Comment: It shows that the error is located where it says await cilent.edit_channel_permissions.

Comment: What message do you send in discord to run this command?

Comment: $maketicket {subject}